# Symfony 3.4 : Render multiple array in twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I got a form with CollectionType that stores an array in an SQLite database, this is  the structure of the entity object returned in the controller:

```
Expertations {#666 ▼
-id: 9
  -date: DateTime @1536749818 {#653 ▶}
  -client: 1
  -status: 0
  -price: 0.0
  -expiration: DateTime @1536749818 {#650 ▶}
  -tipo: 1
  -kw: 12
  -piani_casa: 2
  -riscaldamento: "1"
  -opere_murarie: false
  -trifase: false
  -sconto: 10.0
  -level: 1
  -square_meters: 140
  -floor: array:6 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 1
    2 => 2
    3 => 2
    4 => 2
    5 => 2
  ]
  -ambient: array:6 [▼
    0 => Rooms {#671 ▼
      -id: 10
      -name: "Cucina"
      -level: 1
      -sq_meter_from: 0.0
      -sq_meter_to: 999.0
      -punti_prese: 5
      -punti_luce: 1
      -prese_tv: 1
    }
    1 => Rooms {#649 ▶}
    2 => Rooms {#670 ▶}
    3 => Rooms {#669 ▶}
    4 => Rooms {#649 ▶}
    5 => Rooms {#668 ▶}
  ]
  -name: array:6 [▼
    0 => "Cucina"
    1 => "Soggiorno"
    2 => "Corridoio"
    3 => "Camera Padronale"
    4 => "Camera Figlia"
    5 => "Bagno"
  ]
  -pp: array:6 [▼
    0 => 5
    1 => 4
    2 => 2
    3 => 4
    4 => 4
    5 => 2
  ]
  -pl: array:6 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 1
    2 => 2
    3 => 1
    4 => 1
    5 => 2
  ]
  -pt: array:6 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 1
    2 => 0
    3 => 1
    4 => 1
    5 => 0
  ]
  -num_circuiti: 5
  -num_prese_telefono_dati: 3
  -illum_sicurezza: 2
  -spd: 1
  -imp_ausiliari: 1
}
```

This should be rendered in a twig template as a table, much of the data is retrieved using a simple array access like `{{ item.string }}`.
The fields named `floor, ambient, name, pp, pl, pt` should be rendered in the column, one row for item (you should see that in this example all the elements contains 5 keys).

I've tried to access the array as usual but I got an error relating trying to access a key that in reality is an integer (shouldn't made?)

here is the twig for loop that don't work:

```
{% for items in item %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ items.floor }}</td>
    <td>{{ items.ambient }}</td>
    <td>{{ items.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ items.pp }}</td>
    <td>{{ items.pl }}</td>
    <td>{{ items.pt }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The error returned is: `Impossible to access an attribute ("floor") on a integer variable ("1").`

Expected Behaviour:

These items should be rendered in the table, eg: row one, show `floor.0` value, `ambient.0.name, name.0` value, `pp.0` value, `pl.0` value, `pt.0` value`, column two etc..

Will someone got the solution to render it correctly?

Comment: Start with `{% for item in items %}`

Comment: @DarkBee the variable passed from controller is item, items not exist and will be created by the for loop

Comment: If you are returning one item, then why do u have the loop? Just access with e.g. `item.id`

Comment: Also `floors` is an array, so u would need a loop for that  as well e.g. `{% for number, persons in item.floors %}Room #{{ number }}'s max persons: {{ persons }}`

Comment: When i render the page, i get one item, in this case the expertation, this item will return static values from the entity and these 5 arrays should populate the table, every key for every row. I was thinking that maybe I should create an array that contains the others array such as data => [ floor => '..', ambient => ''...", name => '...' etc. ] - Or something like [0] =>[ 'floor' => '1' , ambient => '18', name => 'test' etc.], '1' => ['floor' => '1', ambient => '5', name => 'test2' etc..]. how can i do this in controller? at the time I'm getting the array with find($id)

Comment: You can't iterate object properties in `twig`. You would first need to cast it to a real array

Comment: how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For a single Expertations object (named yourObject) the loop should look like this:

```
{% for key in yourObject.floor|keys %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ yourObject.floor[key] }}</td>
        <td>{{ yourObject.ambient[key] }}</td>
        <td>{{ yourObject.name[key] }}</td>
        <td>{{ yourObject.pp[key] }}</td>
        <td>{{ yourObject.pl[key] }}</td>
        <td>{{ yourObject.pt[key] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```